# How to test MySQL transactions?

Tags: mysql, debugging, transactions

I have a question about testing the queries in a transaction. I've been using MySQL transactions for quite some time now, and everytime I do this, I use something like:

```
$doCommit = true;
$error = "";
mysql_query("BEGIN");

/* repeat this part with the different queries in the transaction
   this often involves updating of and inserting in multiple tables */
$query = "SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, etc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
    $error .= mysql_error() . " in " . $query . "<BR>";
    $doCommit = false;
}
/* end of repeating part */

if($doCommit){
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {
    echo $error;
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Now, it often happens that I want to test my transaction, so I change `mysql_query("COMMIT");` to `mysql_query("ROLLBACK");`, but I can imagine this is not a very good way to test this kind of stuff. It's usually not really feasable to copy every table to a temp_table and update and insert into those tables and delete them afterwards (for instance because tables maybe very large). Of course, when the code goes into production relevant error-handling (instead of just printing the error) is put into place.

What's the best way to do stuff like this?

Comment: Oh dear... Just found out that PHP does not support anything like `finally` or `ensure`.

Comment: Yeah I know... PHP sucks and I use it...

Comment: There is now support for `finally`, as of PHP 5.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, there is a bug in your implementation.  If a query errors out, the current transaction is automatically rolled back and then closed.  So as you continue to execute queries, they will not be within a transaction (they will be commited to the DB).  Then, when you execute `Rollback`, it'll silently fail.  From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html):

```
Rolling back can be a slow operation that may occur implicitly without the user 
having explicitly asked for it (for example, when an error occurs).
```

The explicit command `ROLLBACK` should only be used if you determine in the application that you need to rollback (for reasons other than a query error).  For example, if you're deducting funds from an account, you'd explicitly rollback if you found out the user didn't have enough funds to complete the exchange...

As far as testing the transactions, I do copy the database.  I create a new database and install a set of "dummy data".  Then I run all the tests using an automated tool.  The tool will actually commit the transactions and force rollbacks, and check that the expected database state is maintained throughout the tests.  Since it's harder to programatically know the end state from a transaction if you have an unknown input to the transaction, testing off of live (or even copied-from-live) data is not going to be easy.  You can do it (and should), but don't depend upon those results for determining if your system is working.  Use those results to build new test cases for the automated tester...

Comment: Wow, I haven't done my homework right on this one then... I really didn't know MySQL rolls back when an error occurs. Thanks for that insight. Thanks for the rest as well, this is a really helpful post.

Comment: Sure.  I see that error quite often (as it's counter-intuitive if you're not expecting it)...  It's also quite a hard issue to debug when you're going through looking at an execution log trying to figure out why a few queries got committed even though the rollback command was executed...  That's why I always throw exceptions on query errors (Especially considering production code should never error unless something went really wrong (like the server went away).  So why bother trying to continue on if you don't know what went wrong?)...  It's a lot harder to ignore that way as well...

Comment: You're right. In your post you talk about an automated tester, did you make that yourself? I can imagine different testers are needed for different projects (and maybe even for different test-cases).

Comment: I simply use PHPUnit.  While it's not a unit test, it's still a good framework for automating tests.  And yes, each project gets its own set of test cases.  Actually, I use a different set of test cases for each model...

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it's really helpful. I'm going to check out PHPUnit (I have to admit we don't use unit tests at the company where I work.) It's small company, so I may try to introduce it to the rest.

Comment: There's no better time to start testing than now.  Remember that you don't need 100% coverage to gain benefits from automated testing.  Add tests as you go, and over time build up the coverage.  But PHPUnit is so flexible that you can use it as a harness to run whatever type of test that you want.  You can do interface testing through Selenium (via a PHPUnit extension).  You can do database testing.  You can do integration testing.  The benefits are there, and you can start reaping them with a single test case (Obviously the more you add the better).  But a step in the right direction is good.

Comment: What tool are you using for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could refactor your first example and use some DB access wrapper class?

In that wrapper class you can have a variable $normalCommit = true;
and a method SetCommitMode() which sets that $normalCommit variable.
And you have a method Commit() which commits if($normalCommit == true)
Or even have a variable $failTransaction which calls mysql_query("ROLLBACK"); if you wish (so you could pass/fail many sequential tests).

Then when you run the test, you can set somewhere in the test code file:
$myDBClass->SetCommitMode(false);
or
$myDBClass->RollBackNextOperation(true);
before the operation which you wish to fail, and it will just fail. In such a way the code which you are testing will not contain those fail/commit checks, only the DB class will contain them.

And normally ONLLY the test code (especially if you do unit testing) should call those SetCommitMode and RollBackNextOperation methods, so you accidentally do not leave those calls in the production code.

Or you could pass some crazy data to your method (if you are testing a method), like negative variables to save in UNSIGNED fields, and then your transaction should fail 100% if your code does not do commit after such an SQL error (but it should not).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's a sane solution. If I could split the bounty you would've gotten 50%...

Answer (score 2):

Generally I use something like (I use pdo for my example):

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
  $db->exec('INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE');
  $db->commit();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  $db->rollBack();
  // rethrow the error or
}
```

Or if you have your own exception handler, use a special clause for your PDOExceptions, where to rollback the execution. Example:

```
function my_exception_handler($exception) {
  if($exception instanceof PDOException) {
    // assuming you have a registry class
    Registry::get('database')->rollBack();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but how do you test your transaction? The point of my question is that I want to know how you can test all the queries in one transaction. In your case I woul replace the `$db->commit();` with `$db->rollBack();`, but that would be the same as I did in my original question.