# SQL, how to test concurrent transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, transactions

Lets say that there is a table `something` with columns `id, foo, bar, baz, qux, norf, updated_at` and one wants to test various use cases that can occur when it comes to concurrent transactions that are working something on this table, for example:

*Use case:* if you check below transactions **T1** and **T2**, for example how to test at which transaction isolation level inserts from **T2** will be  available in second SELECT, assuming that **T2** will COMMIT between first and second SELECT in **T1?**

So i'm testing here some variation of `phantom read` i guess, although SELECT statements are different **?**

My only idea is to use `SELECT PG_SLEEP(N);` between two SELECT statements and to open two DB connections (for example 2 instances of some DB client, such as PgAdmin) one to handle **T1** and one to handle **T2** than manually to start **T1** letting first SELECT to finish where `PG_SLEEP(10)` will fire, than to manually start **T2**, *and hoping to see results set from **T1*** and to compare it manually. But it seems that is not possible because i didnt find any DB client that can return multiple result sets from 2+ SELECT statements.

(By the way it would be great to use one SELECT instead of two, somehow to merge to one SELECT but i don't see the way how to do it)

**T1:**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
SELECT sum(foo) as foo
FROM something
WHERE bar = 1 AND updated_at <= '...' AND norf = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(foo)
FROM something
WHERE bar = 1 AND baz IN (1, 9, 10) AND updated_at > '...'
GROUP BY bar;

SELECT PG_SLEEP(10);

SELECT bar, qux, sum(foo) AS foo
FROM something
WHERE norf = 2
GROUP BY bar, qux;

COMMIT;
```

**T2:**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
INSERT INTO something VALUES(...);
...
COMMIT;
```

Please don't post answer such as "READ COMMITTED is default transaction level in postgre you don't need to specify it" i'm using it just as an example, or "you will solve problem by using REPEATABLE READ in postgre" because i would like to get that answer from testing.

Although i mentioned postgre on few places i'm using `mysql` and `sql-server` because question is not tied to neither of them.

Also i checked already proposed questions:
[How to test MySQL transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448217/how-to-test-mysql-transactions)
[How to test concurrency locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944869/how-to-test-concurrency-locally)

Comment: Are you really using MySQL and SQL Server and Postgresql here? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Sql Server, I test this type of scenario by opening two different windows in Sql Server Management Studio. Each window has it's own connection to the database. I then execute the relevant portions of T1 and T2, step by step, to reproduce the desired test case.

I'm sure you can do something very similar with other databases with their respective tooling.

Example:

**Window 1**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
SELECT sum(foo) as foo
FROM something
WHERE bar = 1 AND updated_at <= '...' AND norf = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(foo)
FROM something
WHERE bar = 1 AND baz IN (1, 9, 10) AND updated_at > '...'
GROUP BY bar;
```

**Window 2**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
...
INSERT INTO something VALUES(...);
...
COMMIT;
```

**Window 1**

```
SELECT bar, qux, sum(foo) AS foo
FROM something
WHERE norf = 2
GROUP BY bar, qux;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I was close and yet so far, thank you on great explanation